# gmake overriding compiler directory

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, gnu-make

Is there any way to specify gmake an alternate compiler directory. ie: i have multiple compilers installed and trying to use alternate gcc while compilation.

like if i specify it uses the new specified gcc.

```
gmake CC=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/gcc 
    CXX=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/g++ 
    LD=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/gcc 
    AR=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ar
```

what i am trying to avoid is specify absolute path for all tools. i am trying something like

```
gmake COMPILER_DIR=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/
```

this might fit as a cross-compiler question also.

Comment: That entriely depends on your makefile, and how it assembles the compiler command. We can't tell much about it, sicne we dont know it.

Comment: I think there is not much else you can do _reliably_. Makefiles, at least with respect to variable names, are based on [convention](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Utilities-in-Makefiles), to which not every Makefile-author adheres to (unfortunately). But even then, the conventions for tools say nothing about what you try to achieve. Consider writing a wrapper Makefile or shell script for your purposes. Like `DIR=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ && make CC=$DIR/gcc CXX=$DIR/g++ LD=$DIR/ld AR=$DIR/ar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the makefile you can use something like this:

```
CC = $(COMPILER_DIR)gcc
```

If you do not define `COMPILER_DIR` then the normal system `gcc` will be used, otherwise from your directory.

Comment: that's an easy way but will require me to change the makeflags just for porting. It's a good suggestion, just hoping there will be native gmake supposrt for the same.

Comment: marking this as answer, though still hunting for gmake native support, not choosing the one sent by @christanK since it involved writing additional shell script that kinda deviates from the main question.

Comment: well this method does have a problem. incase the product has dependency library which has its own make file shipped, there's no way you can edit the existing makefiles. So the only way it works out is overriding `gmake CC=/installdir/gcc`

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference here's how crosstool tool chainkit suggest.
Method 1
Instead of using complete `/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/` use `PATH=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin` and in make files keep `CC=$(CROSSCOMPILERVERSION)gcc` where `CROSSCOMPILERVERSION=i686-unknown-linux-gnu` somehow this setup works best, still not sure how.

Method 2
Use the path as suggested in method.1 but additionally create softlink in crosstool bin dir. like in `/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin` add softlink of i686-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc as gcc. This is easier than changing makefile (or in cas you dont have permission to change makefiles)

Answer (score 0):

When you build `binutils` and `gcc` they install in two different paths:

- `bin/PREFIX-gcc`
- `PREFIX/bin/gcc`

This allows you to have several cross compilers in your path each with different executables names, but you can also simply put the second variant in your path such that `gcc` is now the cross version of choice.  This is useful for Makefiles.

Your example already uses the second form: `/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ar` as opposed to `/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/i686-unknown-linux-gnu-ar` (which probably also exists on your system).

So you can build with `PATH=/opt/crosstool/gcc-3.2.2-glibc-2.2.5/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/:$PATH make ...` and now the default `gcc` will be the cross version.